# jonkykong/SideMenu is not working in Xcode 11.3 and iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, jonkykong-sidemenu

**Describe the bug**

Clone and run project in xcode 11.3 with Catalina MacOS and example project will not compile.

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Clone/Download project
2. Open it in Xcode 11.3
3. Compile Example Project
4. See error

**Expected behavior**

Example project must compile without
    error.

[image]

Comment: Run `pod update` on the project folder and the two missing files will be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted at in the comments, the project has dependencies which cannot be found.

According to the path that it is complaining about, its missing one or more [Pods](https://cocoapods.org/)

So normally you would go into the project folder in your terminal and enter `pod install` which will install the missing libraries.

Once you have done this open the **workspace** (not the project) and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related to different than expected file structure and naming conventions of the Pod

1. Copy a `Info.plist` from `SideMenu` folder to `Pods->Target Support Files->SideMenu` folder and rename it there to `SideMenu-Info.plist`
2. Copy the `SideMenu.h` from SideMenu folder to `Pods->Target Support Files->SideMenu` folder and rename it there to `SideMenu-umbrella.h`
3. Copy the `SideMenu.h` from `SideMenu` to `Pods->Target Support Files->Pods-Example` and rename it there to `Pods-Example-umbrella.h`
4. Rebuild the project